# Rollup of multiple string columns by id - python

Tags: python, pandas

I got following dataframe in Python:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
              'col1': ['normal', 'well', 'normal', 'normal', 'well', 'normal'],
              'col2': ['bad', 'normal','normal', 'normal', 'normal', 'bad']})
```

I would like to rollup by id but keep in columns strings that are other than 'normal' or 'normal' if there is nothing else ('well' or 'bad'). Something like following:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                'col1': ['well', 'well', 'normal'],
                'col2': ['bad', 'normal', 'bad']})
```

I was thinking about sorting and then using groupby and .first but not sure how to get desired levels on the top in each column.

Comment: I think you should open up business logic of this case more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by `NaN`s first if no `NaN`s values before [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
d = d.replace('normal', np.nan).groupby('id').first().fillna('normal')
#alternative solution
d = d.mask(d == 'normal').groupby('id').first().fillna('normal')
```

---

```
print (d)
      col1    col2
id                
1     well     bad
2     well  normal
3   normal     bad
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Categorical to define order

```
cats = ['well', 'bad', 'normal']
d = d.assign(
    col1=pd.Categorical(d.col1, cats, ordered=True),
    col2=pd.Categorical(d.col2, cats, ordered=True)
)

d.groupby('id', as_index=False).min()

   id    col1    col2
0   1    well     bad
1   2    well  normal
2   3  normal     bad
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a helper key for helping sort, then we do `groupby`

```
helpkey={'well':1,'bad':2,'normal':3}

s=d.set_index('id').groupby('id')[['col1','col2']].apply(lambda x : x.apply(lambda y: sorted(y,key=helpkey.get)))

# using all for find the row only have normal ,then we drop it.
s[~(s=='normal').all(1)].reset_index()

Out[568]: 
   id    col1    col2
0   1    well     bad
1   2    well  normal
2   3  normal     bad
```